# mobile development using flex sdk only?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder, flex-mobile

I have been trying to figure out whether it is possible to use only flex sdk for mobile development.

Do I really have to purchase and use Flex Builder? are there free tools that would allow me to package my application for, say, iOS or Android?

In the past I have developed several SWF applications using flex sdk and emacs only. Can I do the same for mobile platforms?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AIR SDK and its associated command line tools without using Flash Builder (although there are several steps involved in producing the mobile applications).  You can get the AIR 3 SDK here:

http://www.adobe.com/special/products/air/sdk/

Comment: You do need the Flex SDK, too. The AIR SDK doesn't include the compiler or debugger. The Flex SDK contains an AIR SDK, but since AIR 3 just came out, I'm not sure a version of Flex is available with it yet.

Answer (score 2):

[FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org) is the most popular, efficient and simplest free alternative to FlashBuilder. I develop using both of them (depending on which team I work with) and I prefer FD by far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to do that. FlashBuilder is only a convenience IDE for development. As long as you have the (freely available) SDK, you can use any editor to write your code and then compile against the SDK.

All you need to ensure is that unlike a standard flex app, you would need the additional necessary mobile device files. You can check this out for reference (ignoring the FlashBuilder part) - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/hello-world.html